# Kentico CMS 10 - DocumentHelper Attachment URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

When using the CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentHelper to retrieve documents of a custom page type, how would one get the path of an image attached to a Direct Uploader form control property type?

If documents/page are being retrieved in the following way:

```
DocumentQuery documents = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("Custom.PageType")
   .Path("/some-path", PathTypeEnum.Children)
   .OnCurrentSite()
   .Culture("en-us")
   .Published()
   .Page(page, size);
```

Then looping through retrieved documents to project to a custom class:

```
foreach(var document in documents) {
    Foo foo = new Foo(document.getStringValue("SomeCustomColumnName", ""));
    foos.add(foo);
}
```

Using `getStringValue()` targeting the Direct Uploader field/property of the custom page type returns a document GUID such as `"123456f-5fa9-4f64-8f4b-75c52db096d5"`.

In transformations, I can use [GetFileUrl()](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_2/api/html/M_CMS_Controls_TransformationHelper_GetFileUrl_1.htm) such as `GetFileUrl("AttachmentColumnName")` to get the path, how could I use that in ASPX code behind when working with retrieved documents?

The custom page type data is provided to the client via an ASMX service and Ajax. The returned JSON data is used to generate/append markup to the page, including an `<img />`.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this in your item template:

```
/CMSPages/GetFile.aspx?guid=<%# Eval("SomeCustomColumnName")%>
```

You can also check to see if `SomeCustomColumnName` is empty or not before generating that link too if you don't want a broken image.

The other option is to convert that file upload to a URL selector and allow the users to upload files to the media library.  This is probably a better approach IMHO.

Comment: Let's say I'm doing this from code behind in the C#/K# and returning custom page type data in a RESTful way via an ASMX service and Ajax, would I return the GUID and set the `src` attribute of a jQuery generated `<img />` tag to a path like `<img src="/CMSPages/GetFile.aspx?guid=12345-foo-bar" />`? The HTML including loading an image is generated via jQuery/JavaScript and appended to the page. Having a path would allow me to set the `src` easily.

Comment: This part of the path `/CMSPages/GetFile.aspx?guid=` is static.  So set the `guid` query string value as you would in your language of choice.  You're just concatenating a string together essentially.

Comment: That looks like it would work, let me try that and mark the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer to include a second solution as well.

Comment: The URL Selector was definitely a better option. For sake of quality documentation, could you elaborate in your answer about using that form control and programmatically (DocumentHelper) retrieving the value? In case someone has a similar issue.

Comment: There really is no elaboration.  I'd use the same DocumentQuery method you used to get the column data but instead of providing part of a static string like `/CMSPages/GetFile.aspx` I'd just use the full column value like `src='<%# Eval("ColumnName") %>'`

Answer (score 0):

It took me a few hours to figure this out.

In my case, I was able to get the image URL using the following:

```
Guid pageGuid = ValidationHelper.GetGuid(this.GetValue("ProductPage"), new Guid());

// Creates a new instance of the Tree provider
TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);

CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode doc = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments()
    .Where(d => d.NodeGUID == pageGuid)
    .FirstOrDefault();

CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode pageNode = tree
    .SelectNodes()
    .WithGuid(doc.DocumentGUID)
    .OnCurrentSite()

var document = DocumentHelper.GetDocument(pageNode, tree);
Guid imageGuid = document.GetGuidValue("ImageProperty", new Guid());
DocumentHelper.GetAttachmentUrl(imageGuid, 0);
```